# Python: why a dictionary type data could automatically exclude some items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I created a dictionary containing six items as below:

```
 >>> dict1 = {
'A': ['A','A'],
'AB':['A','B'], 
'A':['A','O'],
'B':['B','B'],
'B':['B','O'],
'O':['O','O']
}
```

But when I check the dictionary I found that the items `"{'A': ['A', 'A'], 'B': ['B', 'B']}"` have been excluded.

```
>>> dict1
Out[19]: {'A': ['A', 'O'], 'AB': ['A', 'B'], 'B': ['B', 'O'], 'O': ['O', 'O']}
>>> len(dict1)
Out[17]: 4
```

However if I create a new dictionary with the excluded items.It becomes normal.

```
>>> dict2 ={'A': ['A', 'A'], 'B': ['B', 'B']}
>>> dict2
Out[21]: {'A': ['A', 'A'], 'B': ['B', 'B']}
```

Could anybody explain me why is that?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a python dict so Python automatically replaces the first values by the new ones

Comment: I posted an answer showing how you can assign a lot of values to a specific key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate keys but you can have multiple values. In other words,  **each key is unique.**

So each time you assign new values to the same key, you override the previous values of the key.

A way **to assign 2 values** (or lists) like in your example can be the following:

```
dict1 = {'A': [['A','A'],['A','O']], 'B':[['B','B'],['B','O']], 'O':['O','O'], 'AB':['A','B']}
```

**Result**

```
{'A': [['A', 'A'], ['A', 'O']], 'B': [['B', 'B'], ['B', 'O']], 'AB': ['A', 'B'], 'O': ['O', 'O']}
```

**Finally, you can access each key as follows:**

```
dict1['A']
```

**Result**

```
[['A', 'A'], ['A', 'O']]
```

This seems to be what you want to do.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with dictionaries in Python is that **each key is unique**. That is, when you add an existing entry the previous value stored is overwritten by the new one.

When you typed:

```
dict1 = {
  'A': ['A','A'],
  'AB':['A','B'], 
  'A':['A','O'], # Overrides ['A', 'A']
  'B':['B','B'],
  'B':['B','O'], # Overrides previous entry
  'O':['O','O']
}
```

You gave the dictionary two values for the keys `'A'` and `'B'`. That is you asked the dict to **change** the value previously stored.

I hope my answer was clear enough :)

EDIT: format & language

Answer (score 1):

In the `python dictionary` you cannot have duplicate keys. If any duplicate key is present into the `python dictionary`,  `python` automatically replaces the first values by the new ones. `python dictionary` behaves as `unique` key.

In your example:

```
dict1 = {
  'A': ['A','A'],
  'AB':['A','B'], 
  'A':['A','O'], # 'A': ['A','A'] and 'A': ['A','O'] override.
  'B':['B','B'],
  'B':['B','O'], # 'B': ['B','B'] and 'B': ['B','O'] override.
  'O':['O','O']
}
```

Then your `dictionary` will be:

```
dict1 = {
  'A': ['A','O'],
  'AB':['A','B'], 
  'B':['B','O'],
  'O':['O','O']
}
```

I think, It will be helpfull .

Answer (score 1):

As Python Documentation says

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary). A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way dictionaries are written on output.
>
> The main operations on a dictionary are storing a value with some key and extracting the value given the key. It is also possible to delete a key:value pair with del. If you store using a key that is already in use, the old value associated with that key is forgotten. It is an error to extract a value using a non-existent key.

Reference : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html